# How to keep running Capistrano 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

With Capistrano 3 out and Mavericks and Yosemite released... or if you had a recent clean install on of Rails and Capistrano on your development machine you may end up getting errors when trying to deploy a Rails 3.X app due to your machine having Capistrano 3.0 being installed.

If you are getting errors about Capistrano 3 being unable to read your deploy.rb file...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your Gemfile, change your reference to Capistrano to the [last version](http://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano/versions/2.15.5) published in 2.0 (as of this writing).

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.9'
  #other development gems...
end
```

On your local machine, make sure you have that version installed

```
gem install capistrano -v 2.15.9
```

Comment: Very useful! 
For those of us who don't have a ruby project but use capistrano there is no gem file to edit. Also the following commands could be useful:
"gem which capistrano" and "gem env"

Comment: On an old project i still run capistrano 2, but i get the error above. My gem file uses 2.15.5 but "gem which capistrano" shows capistrano v3. How can i force to run on capistrano 2?

Comment: @pastullo did you try running bundle install to create a new Gemfile.lock?

Comment: so which version shows in your Gemfile.lock? Can you try gem list to see which versions are installed?

Comment: If you aren't doing ruby, then you can run `cap _2.15.5_ deploy` after the gem is installed.

Comment: @creativereason i need capistrano 2 for my old app. `gem which capistrano` says 3, but everything else (gem list(says 3.2.1, 2.15.5), gemfile, gemfile.lock) all say 2.15.5. thoughts?

Comment: @TreyCopeland how is it referred to in your Gemfile? Do you manually reference 2?

Comment: @creativereason yes, i have `gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.5'`

Comment: It looks like the latest is Capistrano 2.15.9 now. https://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano/versions/2.15.9 (I checked the source at https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/tree/legacy-v2)

Answer (score 4):

You can run gem wrapper scripts using a version specifier.

The following should run capistrano 2.x, if it's installed (see `gem list --local´):

```
cap "_<3_" --version
```